# Can't Access Camera from iMessage App

Tags: ios, swift, camera, imessage-extension

As the title suggests, I am trying to access the camera inside a view on my iMessage app extension. This code works fine on a normal app, but nothing shows up with my iMessage extension. I have the info.plist set up as well.

Thank you.

```
import UIKit
import Messages
import AVFoundation

class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!

var session : AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput : AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var videoPreviewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    alignment()
}

func alignment() {

    cameraView.bounds.size.width = view.bounds.size.width / 4
    cameraView.bounds.size.height = cameraView.bounds.size.width
    cameraView.layer.cornerRadius = cameraView.bounds.size.width / 2

}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    session = AVCaptureSession()
    session!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let videoDevices = AVCaptureDevice.devices(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    for device in videoDevices! {

        let device = device as! AVCaptureDevice
        if device.position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front {

            captureDevice = device

        }

    }

    //We will make a new AVCaptureDeviceInput and attempt to associate it with our backCamera input device.
    //There is a chance that the input device might not be available, so we will set up a try catch to handle any potential errors we might encounter.
    var error : NSError?
    var input : AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {

        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDevice)

    } catch let error1 as NSError {

        error = error1
        input = nil
        print(error!.localizedDescription)

    }

    if error == nil && session!.canAddInput(input) {

        session!.addInput(input)

        // The remainder of the session setup will go here...

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput?.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey : AVVideoCodecJPEG]

        if session!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {

            session!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            //configure live preview here

            videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            videoPreviewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            videoPreviewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait

            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

            session!.startRunning()

        }

    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    videoPreviewLayer!.frame = cameraView.bounds
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Conversation Handling

override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
    // Called when the extension is about to move from the inactive to active state.
    // This will happen when the extension is about to present UI.

    // Use this method to configure the extension and restore previously stored state.
}

override func didResignActive(with conversation: MSConversation) {
    // Called when the extension is about to move from the active to inactive state.
    // This will happen when the user dissmises the extension, changes to a different
    // conversation or quits Messages.

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers,
    // and store enough state information to restore your extension to its current state
    // in case it is terminated later.
}

override func didReceive(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
    // Called when a message arrives that was generated by another instance of this
    // extension on a remote device.

    // Use this method to trigger UI updates in response to the message.
}

override func didStartSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
    // Called when the user taps the send button.
}

override func didCancelSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation) {
    // Called when the user deletes the message without sending it.

    // Use this to clean up state related to the deleted message.
}

override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    // Called before the extension transitions to a new presentation style.

    // Use this method to prepare for the change in presentation style.
}

override func didTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle) {
    // Called after the extension transitions to a new presentation style.

    // Use this method to finalize any behaviors associated with the change in presentation style.
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use camera inside a view in iMessage app extension,then please give Camera access permission in in both info.plist file of project and info.plist file of MessageExtension like this:

In info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>To take a pic.</string>
```

After give permission you should Write Following:

```
import UIKit
import Messages
import AVFoundation


class MessagesViewController: MSMessagesAppViewController
{

@IBOutlet weak var cameraView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var CaptureBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var capturedImage: UIImageView!

var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var stillImageOutput: AVCaptureStillImageOutput?
var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?

var captureDevice : AVCaptureDevice?

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    cameraView.frame = view.bounds
    cameraView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSession!.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto

    let backCamera = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    var error: NSError?
    var input: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    do {
        input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: backCamera)
    } catch let error1 as NSError {
        error = error1
        input = nil
    }

    if error == nil && captureSession!.canAddInput(input) {
        captureSession!.addInput(input)

        stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput()
        stillImageOutput!.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
        if captureSession!.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput) {
            captureSession!.addOutput(stillImageOutput)

            previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
            previewLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
            previewLayer!.connection?.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
            cameraView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer!)

            captureSession!.startRunning()
        }
    }

}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    previewLayer!.frame = cameraView.bounds
}
@IBAction func CaptureBtn_Pressed(_ sender: Any)
{
    if let videoConnection = stillImageOutput!.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo) {
        videoConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
        stillImageOutput?.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from: videoConnection, completionHandler: {(sampleBuffer, error) in
            if (sampleBuffer != nil) {
                let imageData = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation(sampleBuffer)
                let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: imageData as! CFData)
                let cgImageRef = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: CGColorRenderingIntent.defaultIntent)

                let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef!, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)
                self.capturedImage.image = image
            }
        })
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Conversation Handling

override func willBecomeActive(with conversation: MSConversation)
{

}

override func didResignActive(with conversation: MSConversation)
{
}

override func didReceive(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)
{

}

override func didStartSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)
{
}

override func didCancelSending(_ message: MSMessage, conversation: MSConversation)
{

}

override func willTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle)
{

}

override func didTransition(to presentationStyle: MSMessagesAppPresentationStyle)
{

}

}
```